# Creating unique buffer for each set of points separately and in one procedure using QGIS?

Tags: buffer, qgis-3

How could I create a buffer for each set of points (colour group) separately and in one procedure in QGIS 3?

The image below shows a subset of points for buffering.

[image: Points for buffering]

Answer (score 4):

In your Attribute Table, you need to create (unless you already have it) a field which will define the unique buffer distance for each of your points.

Then you will be able to accomplish the buffering process by applying

> Vector > Geoprocessing Tool > Variable distance buffer

**Elongation:**

- If I have correctly understood the question gist, you are able to execute buffering "separately" by choosing the *"Selected features only"* in the "Variable distance buffer". Those selected features can be achieved beforehand through the basic "Selection by Expression".
- Be careful with units. The buffer size is always applied in the layer CRS units.
- There is an alternative way to accomplish this task with [MMQGIS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/).
- Moreover, it is possible to apply [v.buffer](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.buffer.html) from GRASS GIS library.

---

A short practical example based on [Airports data](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/airports/) from Natural Earth.

In Attribute Table of the Airports layer, I will use an already created attribute *"wdid_score"* which is an integer type and looks like distance in meters.
[image: Example_of_the_attribute]

Then (after CRS adjustment) I proceeded with Variable distance buffer. See image below.
[image: Variable_distance_buffer]

---

**References:**

- [Variations in buffering](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html#variations-in-buffering)
- [QGIS buffer points, buffer amount in attribute value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197214/qgis-buffer-points-buffer-amount-in-attribute-value)
- [How to buffer vectors from fields in QGIS using Python](https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/11/28/how-to-buffer-vectors-from-fields-in-qgis-using-python/)
- [A easy way to create buffer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251692/a-easy-way-to-create-buffer-in-qgis)
- [Understanding QGIS buffer tool units?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23856/understanding-qgis-buffer-tool-units)
- [Does QGIS Buffer Tool use units of CRS? [duplicate]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237090/does-qgis-buffer-tool-use-units-of-crs)
- [Create buffer in meters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106988/create-buffer-in-meters)

Comment: Thanks Taras - I see, but needed to buffer each group separately using the same radius - found a response from @Kazuhito suggesting just to buffer all together then dissolve on attribute basis (Dissolve tool GDAL)..this worked!

Comment: [@Bruce T.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/94650/bruce-t), can you please adjust your question in case if I misled the idea behind it. And by any means [@Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito) deserves appreciation, however, it would be nicer if you [@Bruce T.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/94650/bruce-t) can embed his response into your question as a reference. Thanks